# How to really delete Docker blobs and images to free up space in a private Docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am having trouble clearing up disk space in a private docker registry I am running. I am also having trouble understanding all the different digest SHAs returned by Docker API calls.

My private docker registry is setup in `.../docker/registry/v2` It contains two folders: `blobs` (~1.4GB) and `repositories` (~944KB). I've pushed several repositories and multiple tags there.

At first I only needed to remove repo's/tags from being returned by some API calls for front-end display but now I need to free up disk space and can't figure out how.

**1. Remove Repo and tag names (cosmetic)**

I list docker repositories with their tags on a user front-end by parsing the results of the Docker API calls `GET /_catalog` and `GET /<repo name>/tags/list` for each repo. Sometimes I need to delete things so they don't show up in this list and I've been able to do that with the following approach.

`GET /<repo name>/manifests/<tag>`

`DELETE /<repo name>/manifests/<digest SHA in headers.Docker-Content-Digest of the above response>`

I'm not sure this is the right way to do this but I needed to somehow control the front-end display and this has worked for now.

This operation reduces the size of the local `repositories` folder by a few KB but doesn't affect the `blobs` folder.

**2. Clear up disk space and really delete repo's**

Where I'm stuck is how to actually free up the large disk space taken up by the `blobs` directory. There are many different digest SHAs that are returned by `GET /<repo name>/manifests/<tag>`: `body.config.digest` and the various `body.layers[i].digest`.

I tried executing `DELETE /<repo name>/blobs/<some digest>` on these different digests. For some it is successful, for others it says blob not found. When successful the `repositories` directory size is reduced by a few KB but `blobs` directory size doesn't change.

I only tried this after I already hit `DELETE /<repo name>/manifests/<headers.Docker-Content-Digest>` because I didn't want to accidentally break something and not be able to remove the repo's/tags from the front-end.

**My question is**: what is the correct way to clear space due to repo's/tags from a private docker registry. My hope is that the best practice will also delete them from the `/_catalog` and `/<repo name>/tags/list` as well.

Any insight on the use/meaning of the different digests discussed above would also be greatly appreciated.